# Editing Column names

Tags: claims-based-auth, edit-form

How to edit a column name in Sharepoint ?When O  rename a column I can't get by the code to column name.

```
           if (properties.List.Title == "Wpisy")
       {
           SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Szczegoly"];
           SPListItem item = lstOtherList.AddItem();

           item["Kontrakt"] = properties.AfterProperties["Kontrakt1"];
           item["Pracownik"] = properties.AfterProperties["Pracownik1"];
           item["Dzien"] = properties.AfterProperties["DzienStart"];

           item.Update();
       }
       base.ItemAdding(properties);
```

I must change a name for columns, and this is works, but i don't want to always build a new list from the begining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every column in SharePoint has 3 names:

- InternalName (just called Name in `<Field>` and `<FieldRef>` elements)
- StaticName
- DisplayName (called Title in SPField)

InternalName can't be changed after field has been created
StaticName can be changed through code
DisplayName can  be changed through code/UI

When accessing data/fields you should always use ID (often from [SPBuiltInFieldId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.aspx)), InternalName (often using [GetFieldByInternalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.getfieldbyinternalname.aspx) and then ID, but also directly as when accessing AfterProperties) or StaticName (often using [TryGetFieldByStaticName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.trygetfieldbystaticname.aspx) and then ID)

Comment: Yes, but i don't want to use CALM. Maybe it is more easy use ?

Comment: But how can I write theme ? In the Label, or console ?